# How exactly to do a Subversion pre-1.5 style merge?

Tags: svn, merge, rebase, tree-conflict

I have to deal with Subversion 1.4 merges at the moment and have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008681/svn-unable-to-merge-branch-back-into-trunk-numerous-tree-conflicts/1008805#1008805) to a question, which exactly describes my problem. The actual question deals with `git`-style rebase and merge problems with SVN which produce tree conflicts. It includes the following recommendation:

> [...] instead of range-merging the branch to a working copy that points to the trunk, you want to merge "FROM trunk@HEAD TO branch@HEAD" with the working copy pointing to trunk. In essence:
>
> "Give me all the changes I'd need to make trunk identical to branch".

Now I wonder how to actually do that merge with SVN, since `svn merge` only merges to the working directory. Is there a typo in the original answer or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After `svn merge` you need to `svn ci`, and the merge is committed to the branch
2. With Subversion 1.4, the best way to handle merging is with [svnmerge.py](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py)

Comment: 1. Yes, but without merge tracking you'd get tree conflicts when merging back to trunk (reintegration)
2. Thanks, a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me you would need to merge the difference between branch head and trunk head into trunk, so that would be "FROM branch@HEAD TO trunk@HEAD", not the other way around.

There is a merge syntax where you merge the difference between two tags into your working copy. This would be the one to use. (Sorry for being so vague, but I had't done much SVN before 1.5.)