# Tree conflicts in SVN (subclipse)

Tags: svn

I have been working on a branch for a while, and deleted a directory (folder) that I do not need. Next, I tried to merge from the trunk to get any changes. In the process of this merge, the SVN complains about tree conflicts. As a result, when I tried to commit the changes to my branch, SVN did not allow me to do it. It seems that the directory I deleted from my local branch does not exist any more in my local workspace, but it still exists on the trunk. Does anybody know how to resolve this kind of tree conflicts? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify what version of SVN you are on?

Comment: That's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally tree conflicts occur when you have simultaneous changes (add/remove/modify) both on the source and the destination branch directories.
If you want to simply ignore these conflicts caused by something on the trunk that you are not ready to absorb into your branch - then its fairly simple.You can run "svn resolve" on your conflicted directory (in your branch workspace) - then the branch workspace will let you commit again. 
See here for details: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html
(I think in some older versions like 1.4.4 the command used to be *svn resolved* you may want to check the details before you run it)? 
I dont know if it is as simple in your case (for eg., if you want to indeed absorb the changes made in the trunk, then you may need to consider but that is a whole different story and I hope you are not going to need it :-) )

---

EDIT:MORE REF FROM SO:

Here is another link which might help with some more details
[How to 'fix' a SVN branch/tree conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591871/how-to-fix-a-svn-branch-tree-conflict/1592253#1592253)