# Tortoise SVN Merge Dry Run successful but then fails

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am merging a branch back into trunk using re-intergrate. The dry run succeeds without any conflicts so I proceed to merge and get the following error

> Working copy 'D:\Repositories\FwCore\'
>   locked Error reading spooled Report
>   request response Please execute
>   'Cleanup' command

Cleanup does not do anything. I have merged the trunk into the branch so that I can merge the branch back into trunk without problems. This has worked before, but now I am running into this problem and I have no idea what to do, not to mention is very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. It can be quick or very long depending on how much you changed in your branch. In my case, the problem was deleting a folder named `Framework` (in the branch, while the Trunk's `Framework` folder was untouched) and then creating the same folder at a later stage in the branch in the same place *[I had a couple of other renames/deletions similar to this]*. This caused the confusion for SVN. The other problem was renaming a folder and then subsequently deleting it.

On to the fix:

- Follow the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008681/svn-unable-to-merge-branch-back-into-trunk-numerous-tree-conflicts/1008805#1008805------) first
- Switch to your trunk
- Now start a **"Reintegrate a branch"**
- Perform a full merge (not a dry run) and see where the problem folders are
- Now Revert back any changes, and go to each one of these folders and do a **"Merge of a range of revisiosn"**
- Go through the log and select only the revision that deleted/renamed the folder
- Now commit those changes - this is very important (this will delete/rename the folder in trunk)
- Now perform another reintegration on the folder, this time for the next rename/deletion/addition/commit of the problem folder
- Keep doing this until you have no more additions/renames/deletions of the problem folder
- Make sure you commit every time you make a change, otherwise things will go bad again
- Perform these steps on all the problem folders
- Once all the problem folders have been fixed, perform a **"Reintegrate a branch"** one more time on trunk itself. This time everything should go smoothly. If there is another tree conflict, revert changes, and perform the above steps on the problem folder

I have been able to reproduce this problem on a 'dummy' repository. I will submit a suggestion to tortoise SVN team to take this kind of situation into account and let it perform the steps automatically when re-integrating branches

Comment: This can also occur if you have svn:externals with folders of the same name. Simply manually deleting the svn:externals folders in your working copy will let the merge continue.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the net -- looks like the same situation as yours.. perhaps you can get some insight with this http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/970b711c494707b2?hide_quotes=no

Comment: Thanks for the link. That seems to be very similar to my by the author of thread does not explain how he/she solved the problem