# SVN Pulling Changes Into Branch Then Merging Back Into Trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

So I have a project that I am working on with other developers. The setup we have is "Trunk" which holds our project and branches "DevItem1" and "DevItem2" that branched from the Trunk. Since the branches changes have been made to all three and committed respectively. Both branches need the changes that were committed to the "Trunk" before they develop further.

I have tried merging the trunk into each branch, doing some development that has commits and then merging back into the trunk. When I do a plain merge on the truck as a working copy, I get tree conflicts with the commits that were pulled from the trunk into the branch.

If I do a 2 way merge (merging trunk and a branch into my working copy of trunk) I get no conflicts, but I don't pull in the commit messages and history from the branch into the trunk which we would like to have.

What is the proper way to pull something like this off?

Note: I am trying to do as much as possible via TortoiseSVN GUI, but am open to command line answers if it cannot be done via the GUI alone.

Answer (score 0):

So the TortoiseSVN process I have followed is outlined in Mikesigs comment on the accepted answer in the question below and is the actual way of pulling in changed from the trunk and then later merging back into the trunk once finished developing on the branch.

My issue was not seeing the branches commit messages, but if you look at the log there is a checkbox "Include merged revisons" which shows all of the branches commit messages along with changes for each one.

[SVN - unable to merge branch back into trunk - numerous tree-conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008681/svn-unable-to-merge-branch-back-into-trunk-numerous-tree-conflicts?rq=1)