# Using TortoiseSVN to Merge .sql files

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, redgate

I used Red Gates SVN Source Control to add 2 databases (one branched off the other essentially) to a repository, one as the trunk and the other as a branch. I'm now trying to merge the branch back into the trunk, but all I get are Tree Conflicts on the .sql files. I've enabled  enable-auto-props = yes and set  *.sql = svn:mime-type=text/plain in the config file. Am I missing something? I want to be able to do line-by-line merges like normal code, and having a change log would be handy as well.

Comment: Tree conflicts have appeared before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/738367/422353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be my problem:
[SVN how to resolve new tree conflicts when file is added on two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767763/svn-how-to-resolve-new-tree-conflicts-when-file-is-added-on-two-branches)

Since I had only done "Initial Commits" to the trunk and the branch both versions of the files were being added, thus the conflict. So the solution is to use a external merge tool and then commit the changes. There really needs to be a more elegant solution to this problem.