# svn tree conflict while merging

Tags: svn, merge, tree-conflict

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting tree conflicts in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/why-am-i-getting-tree-conflicts-in-subversion)

I am trying to merge a file located in "main/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt" from trunk into branch. However the folder "dir1/dir2" does not exist in branch and hence I am getting tree conflict. How can I resolve this so that dir1/dir2/somefile.txt gets created on branch automatically?

Currently I am using the following command to merge all the changes in my current working directory:

```
svn merge -r 254933:254935 https://svnrepo.de/analytics/trunk my-analytics-dir
 !     C javasource/com/gsi/webstore/platform/component/analytics/dbmigrate/data
 >   local delete, incoming edit upon merge
```

Comment: Can you merge in the revision where you created the directory on the trunk?

Comment: i am trying to merge into the current directory which was represented by "." at the end of the command. But to avoid confusion I recently changed it to the explicit directory name. This directory is my branch directory.

Comment: Fix your command to reflect real path used - . and my-analytics-dir **are different things**

Comment: [Useful reading](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html)

Answer (score 1):

`svn resolve --accept theirs-full -R javasource/com/gsi/webstore/platform/component/analytics/dbmigrate/data`