# How to resolve conflict of renamed folder of file in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

I have following problem:

I have some common commit A for two branches Branch1 and Branch2.

- Branch1 is a public branch (lies on server)
- Branch2 is a  local branch

In Branch1 I changed file (`BAD_folder/somefile.txt`). Changes were pushed to server. In Branch2 I renamed `BAD_folder` to `folder` and made some changes in `somefile.txt`. I want to merge Branch1 with Branch2, but I get a merge conflict in `BAD_folder/somefile.txt` file.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you merging Branch1 into Branch2, or Branch2 into your Branch1? What kind of conflicts do you have?

Comment: @wasthishelpful, The same problem. Main problem is to apply changes from different (in git understanding) file

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Normally `git merge` is symmetric - so it should not matter which branch is merged where.

Comment: @sleske Yes I was thinking of an other case. My bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rename `folder` to `BAD_folder`, merge or rebase `Branch2` (which might be better when this branch is local) and rename folder back.

1. `git checkout -b _tmp Branch1`
2. `git mv folder BAD_folder && git commit`
3. `git merge Branch2`
4. `git mv BAD_folder && git commit`

When you did a rebase, you can do an additional `git rebase -i Branch1` and remove the two `git mv` operations.

`merge` in point 3 works much better when filenames did not change but you might still have to resolve conflicts.