# SVN how to get original version of conflict file from server?

Tags: svn, command-line

This is totally newbie question but I can't find any answer elsewhere

When I update my library (should be readonly) with

```
svn update
```

it said

```
Tree conflict on 'lib/some_meowingful_lib-1.1.1.2.jar'
   > local file unversioned, incoming file add upon update
Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help: p
```

Clearly I have modify something here. I want to discard and get updated version from server. What can I do ?
It is same as Git stash (or discard), then pull.

Tried delete the file then (p) postpone (it will show this again when run `svn resolve`), if (r), then this option disappear. Then the file gone. Nothing can be done. `svn update` won't see conflict anymore.

Comment: Is some other process using this jar . See if any other process is running and has this jar loaded ?

Comment: I just want to revert to its original state in SVN repo

Comment: It is like Git discard all change then pull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/why-am-i-getting-tree-conflicts-in-subversion    Please check this

Comment: @parthi my case does not have anything to do with commit. I just want to revert everything back. Simple solution would be clone the svn again in another folder. However, it is 10 GB of data.

Comment: I don't understand, "this option disappear" - which option? "Then the file gone" - in which scenario? After you delete it manually or after you pick (r)? I guess (r) should be fine here, unless you added the file to .gitignore